# Unable to create ComObject "Excel.Application"

Tags: excel, powershell

```
$FilePath = "D:\path\book1.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Sheet1" 
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
```

I am using Powershell 5 to read an Excel file, Office 365 based Excel is installed on my windows 10 machine.

The first statement itself fails. What should I look to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the error message, this will tell us what the issue is :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have a 64-bit Powershell session trying to access a 32-bit COM object.

To check this, try running a 32-bit Powershell (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell`)